# How to exit and then automatically restart code

Tags: python, html, pycharm, cryptography

I have some python code which scrapes a website and reports the live price of a specific crypto. When I use a while loop to keep printing the live price it keeps printing the same price over and over even when the live price on the website has changed. I thought that maybe my code was scraping it and coming to that website too fast so I added a delay using the time module but even after a 1 minute delay it will not display the correct price but instead prints the same price over and over. Manually ending and restarting the code seemed to make this bug go away but I want this program to run 24/7 and email me when a price reaches a certain point. This is my code so far: (BTW I am a beginner)

```py
import requests
import bs4
import time

run = True
while run == True:
    # time.sleep(60)
    res = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/gitcoin/")
    soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    item = soup_obj.select(".priceValue___11gHJ")[0]
    item = item.text
    print(item)
    exit()
```

This has a loop but I have added an exit() function so that it ends and so I can manually restart it. I just need a way for this code to automatically end itself and then restart repeatedly. I am also using the community edition of Pycharm (latest edition).

Comment: I think this is an issue with the web site that exit/restart won't fix. I've run your code with the 1 minute delay and see changes every so often... maybe 5 minutes or so. If I refresh the browser at that time, it also returns to the same number your code does... for just a few seconds. You pull from a static part of the page but the live ticker updates more quickly. I added a parallel exit/restart and it had the same numbers of your original.

Comment: If you can figure out how the live ticker is getting its data, you may be able to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your program to call a subprocess instead of doing the web call itself. That subprocess can call requests, return whatever you want via stdout and exit. There are multiple ways to do this. You could write separate scripts or use `multiprocess.Process`, but in this example I've written a script that calls itself and uses command line parameters to know which role it is playing.

```
import sys

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    # run poller as subprocess so it exits
    import time
    import subprocess as subp
    while True:
        result = subp.run([sys.executable, __file__, "called"], capture_output=True)
        # assuming program returns ascii float in single line
        item = result.stdout.decode("ascii").strip()
        print(item)
        time.sleep(60)
else:
    import requests
    import bs4
    res = requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/currencies/gitcoin/")
    soup_obj = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "lxml")
    item = soup_obj.select(".priceValue___11gHJ")[0]
    item = item.text
    sys.stdout.write(item)
```